# Multiple counts in grep?

Tags: grep

So I have a big log file where each line contains a date. I would like to count the number of lines containing each date.

I came up with an awful solution, consisting of manually typing each of the following commands:

```
grep -c "2014-01-01" big.log
grep -c "2014-01-02" big.log
grep -c "2014-01-03" big.log
```

I could also have written a small Python script, but that seems overkill. Is there a quicker / more elegant solution?

Comment: Which range of dates do you want to check? From 1 to...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can maybe use of a regex and then `uniq -c` to count the results.

See an example:

```
$ cat a
2014-01-03 aaa
2014-01-03 aaa
2014-01-02 aaa
2014-01-01 aaa
2014-01-04 aaa
hello
2014-01-01 aaa
```

And let's look for all the `2014-01-0X`, being `X` a digit, and count them:

```
$ grep -o "2014-01-0[0-9]" a | sort | uniq -c
      2 2014-01-01
      1 2014-01-02
      2 2014-01-03
      1 2014-01-04
```

Note piping to `sort` is needed to make `uniq -c` work properly. You can see more info about it in my answer to [what is the meaning of delimiter in cut and why in this command it is sorting twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22556575/1983854).

Answer (score 3):

Borrowing fedorqui's sample date file - thanks @fedorqui :-)

```
awk '/2014/{x[$1]++}  END{for (k in x) print x[k],k}' file
2 2014-01-01
1 2014-01-02
2 2014-01-03
1 2014-01-04
```

Comment: Good one! I want my copyright also :) Note that multiple matches in the same line would count just once, although the same is happening to the OP with `grep -c`.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 grep '2014-01-01' big.log |wc -l
 grep '2014-01-02' big.log |wc -l
 grep '2014-01-03' big.log |wc -l
```

Hope this will solve ur prob